# How to get ActiveUser after UserProfile edit using SpringSecurity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a page in which user can edit its profile including username. I can get User model with the help of **@AuthenticationPrincipal**  using the below controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editCustomerProfile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editCustomerProfileGet(@AuthenticationPrincipal User  activeUser,Locale locale, Model model) {
Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerByUsername(activeUser.getUsername());
            model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
            return "editCustomer";
        }
```

Update controller method as below:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateCustomerProfilePost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

        customerFormValidator.validate(customer, result);
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
            return "editCustomer";
        }

        List<Customer> customerList = customerService.getAllCustomers();

        for (int i=0; i< customerList.size(); i++){
            if(customer.getUsername().equals(customerList.get(i).getUsername())){
                model.addAttribute("usernameMsg", "Username already exists");
                model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
                return "editCustomer";
            }
        }

        Customer existingCustomer=customerService.getCustomerById(customer.getCutomerId());
        existingCustomer.setCustomerName(customer.getCustomerName());
        existingCustomer.setBillingAddress(customer.getBillingAddress());
        existingCustomer.getBillingAddress().setCustomer(existingCustomer);
        existingCustomer.setShippingAddress(customer.getShippingAddress());
        existingCustomer.getShippingAddress().setCustomer(existingCustomer);
        existingCustomer.setUsername(customer.getUsername());
        existingCustomer.getUser().setUsername(customer.getUsername());
        Customer editedCustomer=customerService.updateCustomer(existingCustomer);

        customerSecurityService.updateEditCustomerUserAuthentication(editedCustomer, request);

        model.addAttribute("message", "Customer Information Updated Successfully.");
        return "editCustomerSuccess";//information page
    }
```

Used method of CustomerSecurityServiceImpl as below:-

```
@Override
    public void updateEditCustomerUserAuthentication(Customer customer, HttpServletRequest request) {
        final Users user = customer.getUser();
        final Authorities authorities = customerService.getUserAuthoritiesById(user.getUsersId());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(),null, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authorities.getAuthority())));
        result.setDetails(user);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);

    }
```

Error after user profile change once and try again raise error as below:-

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/MusicStore] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.emusicstore.controller.RegisterController.editCustomerProfileGet(RegisterController.java:291)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

After editing the user information, it is reflecting correctly but when I again try to edit the same user then **@AuthenticationPrincipal** active user return null. Please advice me how I do add the user in authentication principle to reuse the above **editCustomerProfileGet** method.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you please try with return "redirect:/editCustomerSuccess". I may suspect that your session object will be lost because a new j_session_id will be created but will not make it to the browser mid-request and the next request will use the old j_session_id, loosing the new session object & authetication

Comment: Hi @VimalBera, I had tried but it is still null, I have posted error log in my question post. Kindly check.

Comment: Hey @soewin, I've found possible solution to your problem and answered it. can you please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have passed username as a principal in authentication token, whereas User object needs to be passed which will be used in subsequent authentication calls internally.

Change your code to

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,user.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authorities.getAuthority())));
```

Comment: I had tried you code but still got NPE.
My Security-Context for login as as below and I only used xml jdbc authentication provider:-
<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider>
 <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
   authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority FROM authorities WHERE username = ?"
  users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE useremail = ?" />
 <security:password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder" />
 </security:authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>

Comment: May be I think, I should write for authentication provider manually. Any suggestion.

Comment: Not sure @soewin, because above code works for me. I just reproduced your scenario in my local env and tried mentioned code.

Comment: Can you share me some codes like controller,XML configuration, authentication services, as I am stuck in this for some times. Please help me to overcome it. Thank you.

Comment: Yea, sure I shared it on drive. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7yKeMcb16K0Qkp1cmpLcFIzOVk

Comment: Thank you, I will check and reply you back.

Comment: sorry for late reply.I have tired and it is working now, this is how I did, each time I add the update user and add the user in authentication then I retrieve that user from authentication. I remove AuthenthicationPrinciple annotaion as this only work one time during initial login. I didn't find anyway to re-assign user in AuthenticationPrinciple annotaion.  So basically I fetch user from SecurityContext Authentication. Thank you for your support.